# Vue.js data transfer between child and parent

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am confused about components data.

Parent to Child use props.

Child to Parent use emit.

I am thinking about difference.

What I have learned, emit need event to transfer data.

So, the example, I learned it  always combine event like 'click'

This is point what I confused.

Why child to parent need emit **event** to send data.

I am think about are there certain way send data from child to parent no use event?

Comment: Have you read the docs? They are great and explain everything very carefully. Try it 

Comment: I think you should start reading from here to learn about callbacks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function Also check VueJS docs. There are better ways for data transfer in VueJS. One of them is Vuex. Preferred for most situations.

Comment: see my answer here. Same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312230/vue-parent-component-access-to-child-components-computed-property